# Reference Type values not updating in localStorage with two way data binding in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage

So, I am working with this Vue Project where I came across a problem where Reference Type values are not updating in **localStorage** with two way data binding. Normal strings, numbers, booleans are updated instantly, but reference type values like objects and arrays are not updated in **localStorage** I created a small demo app to see if I'm doing something wrong in the project, but it gave me the same result. Here's the code:

```
Vue.use(Vuex);

let store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        form: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('form')) ?? {
            first: '',
            second: '',
        },
        single: localStorage.getItem('single') ?? '',
    },
    getters: {
        form(state) { return state.form; },
        single(state) { return state.single; },
    },
    mutations: {
        mutateForm(state, payload) {
            state.form = payload;
            localStorage.setItem('form', JSON.stringify(state.form));
        },
        mutateSingle(state, payload) {
            state.single = payload;
            localStorage.setItem('single', state.single);
        },
    },
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app', store,
    computed: {
        form: {
            get() { return store.getters.form; },
            set(value) { store.commit('mutateForm', value); },
        },
        single: {
            get() { return store.getters.single; },
            set(value) { store.commit('mutateSingle', value); },
        },
    },
});
```

and here's the related HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model="form.first">
    <input type="text" v-model="form.second">
    <input type="text" v-model="single">
</div>
```

I coded this in [playcode.io](https://playcode.io). That's why it is not showing any `Vue` imports. Anyways, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Your `v-model` bindings are targeting properties on `form` but not the `form` itself so your computed _setter_ will never fire and thus, your commit will not write to local storage. If you set `strict: true` in your store, you'll see Vuex warns you about modifying state outside of a mutation

Comment: This question is similar to ["computed property set not called in Vue"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62819916/6277151)